# how to edit components in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Ok so I am a complete noob at flash

I have this http://www.flashtuning.net/flash-files/sliding_menu/

I am trying to change all the purple to blue and trying to get rid of the text with the link but I still want it to link to them pages

I have tried to change the colors in flash for each one but it has no effect do I have to create a new action script for it if so what do I need to put in there?

Your help will be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color, open up the config xml for the sliding menu, and alter the following value:

```
<object param="colorElem" value="0x921375"></object>
```

The 0x921375 value is the color purple (approx.). You can use any hex value you would like. See http://html-color-codes.com/ for some possible colors.

There isn't an option for this component to remove the url.

Comment: Thankyou but for somereason when i change the color to #8DC2D3 it shows as black and the scroll bar stays purple and is there any way that i could possibly change it or add some rule so i can clear the link text?

Comment: or maybe just a way to get rid of the scroll bar? im guessing that will be deleted from the fla file?

Comment: ok the color i fixed just really need a way to hide the link text now lol

Comment: For other users that may have the same question, can you clarify if my answer, or another solution, fixed the color issue.

Comment: ok so managed to clear the url text by doing this open the fla with flash, then open the imgMc from the library, click the readme layer and hit f9 to open the as code, find this line

linkBox.tfl.text = this["info"].attributes.url; and comment it out, 
remove the +7 from the linkBox.tfl.width = linkBox.tfl.textWidth +7;
and you're done